# SharePoint - edit search page using SP Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I work on a project that has two different search results pages. When the search scope is This Site the search results page that is used is osssearch.aspx. When the scope is All Sites the search results page is results.aspx - it is some kind of custom search page. I must edit these two pages. I can edit them only using SP Designer. I edited the osssearch.aspx page successfully. But results.aspx is a really strange page - very long and with too much xslt in it. I created changes on it but I can see them only with my account. For all other accounts the change is invisible. I checked-in the page. Any ideas why the changes are invisible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also have to publish the page (checking in the page is not enough).

If this is the Xslt file you update, you also have to checkin the xslt file itself.

As a side note, you should know that there is a [SharePoint dedicated site in the StackExchange Network](http://sharepoint.Stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I published the major version on check in, but I still cannot see the changes with other account. I don't think that the xslt file is a problem. I don't use it, I just added one link on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because when you edit the page, you are modifying the personalized page instead of the global page.  It's very similar to 2007 mysites profiles.  How your profile can look different from how the public views your profile.

If you think the XSLT is the problem, try adding some simple "hello sharepoint" text first to see if another profile sees it.  Do it outside the XSLT, near placeholdermain.  If you can see it, then it is the XSLT.  If not, you have bigger problems.

I've heard, that if you made a new site from the search center template, you have more control over customizing pages.  That's just hear say.